# Selenium IDE: Click command with no ID

Tags: selenium, automation, click

How do I perform click action on a button with no "id".

```
<a class="ui-button altbuttonfix" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('productionreporttoolbar-productionReportToolBarForm'),{'productionreporttoolbar-productionReportToolBarForm-j_idt43':'productionreporttoolbar-productionReportToolBarForm-j_idt43','userId':'11448','reportName':'','statementName':'productionReport.productionReport','token':'','productionReportId':'1000274'},'report');return false" style="" href="#">
      View
```

It's a `class` type. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the class value? I use that as a locator all the time:

```
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-button altbuttonfix"));
e.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class to identify this button in this case it would be

```js
css=a.ui-button.altbuttonfix
```